# How to find the mean and standard deviation?

Tags: statistics, average, means

I have a group of 20 students who took the first exam, and the mean and standard deviation of their grades was 28(±9.15)

They took the second exam. The mean and standard deviation of their grades in the second exam is unknown, but it is less than the first exam by 14(±9.9)

My question is: How to find the mean of their grades AND the standard deviation in the second exam if I am given these numbers only?

Comment: Work with variances instead (note std dev are always positive so your +/- isn't really right).  You have mean and std dev of A (first exam).  And you have mean and std dev of A-B (diff).  That should be enough to get you there.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, had I known how to get there, I would not have posted this question.

Comment: The mean of the second exam looks easy.  The standard deviation looks hard and perhaps impossible  (I would have thought there must be some unstated negative correlation).